# How to get a value from json that contains collection<DATA> in pojo class and set to listview adapter Android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am facing one problem from 2 days on wards how to set a value from `collection<data>` bean class to text-view in adapter

Comment: please provide some code in order to explain your problem

Comment: private Collection<aaa> a1 = new ArrayList<aaa>();  its in pojo class, for aaa pojo how to get values in adapter

Comment: Still not helpful. Please update your question by providing full code of your pojo and adapter.

Comment: post some relevant code.

Comment: in pojo class i am using private Collection<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>(); how to call that addres and set to adpater and show in listview sir.. i tried but its not get me

Comment: Your question in its current state will most likely not be answered as it lacks code and a more detailed explanation of 'one problem'

Answer (score 0):

first let the class be aaa;

```
public class aaa
{
    String name="";

    public String getname()
    {
      return name;
     } 

    public String setname(String name)
    {
      this.name=name;
     } 

}
```

What you can do is send this class to adapter like this:

```
YourAdapter youradapter=new YourAdapter(context,Collection<aaa>);
yourlistview.setAdapter(youradapter);
```

and Adapter classs may look like:

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    Collection<aaa> collection;
    public TestAdapter(Context context,Collection<aaa> collection)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.collection=collection;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return collection.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return collection.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);

//view binding code
//and now if you have a textview to set name from pojo class you can do is:

        textview.setText(collection.get(position).getname);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: for that adapter how to set value in listview json to collection

Comment: YourAdapter youradapter=new YourAdapter(context,Collection<aaa>);
yourlistview.setAdapter(youradapter); here how to set from json data as collection<aaa>

Comment: You need to parse that json data and then add the parsed data into collection..if you will provide the json data i will show you how to parse it and put it into collection!